# Why we have additional 14 unused descriptors in Linux GDT?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am currently studying "Understanding the Linux Kernel, 3rd Edition". It says - Each GDT includes 18 segment descriptors and
14 null, unused, or reserved entries. Unused entries are inserted on purpose so that Segment Descriptors
usually accessed together are kept in the same 32-byte line of the hardware cache. Can someone please explain if the descriptor size is 8 byte and if we consider cache line is 32 byte, how will the additional null descriptors help?

Comment: Have you figured out what the used descriptors are used for?

Comment: Yes. I read about the used ones.

Comment: Do you have a beef with how they are organized?

Comment: No Ignacio. I am in process of learning them in detail. Do you mean to say once I know them I could understand this section, which I can't understand now?

Comment: It would go a long way towards that.

Comment: Is there any reference document or easy reference to understand what is the relation between size of cache line and introduction of additional 14 descriptors.

Comment: ... You're overthinking it. Each cache line can store 4 descriptors. Figure out how each of the 4 descriptors relate to each other.